# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la raíz digital de un número positivo usando Python?

Tags: python, matemáticas

Necesito obtener la raíz digital de un número positivo usando Python, hasta ahora mis algoritmos no funcionan.

En teoría se deben sumar los dígitos de cada numero hasta que quede solo 1 dígito en el número.

Por ejemplo:

```
127 = 1+2+7 = 10
1+0 = 1
```

Por lo tanto la raíz digital de 127 seria `1`.

Este fue mi ultimo algoritmo:

```
def getDigitalRoot(num):
    return num if num==9 else num%9
```

Pero no funciona bien ya que si pongo por ejemplo 99 retorna 0 y tendría que ser 9.

Comment: pues muéstranos esos algoritmos...

Comment: @rnrneverdies me ganaste por 15 segundos....

Comment: "mis algoritmos no funcionan" como ya te han dicho, si pones eso y no escribes lo que has intentado parece una invitación a que hagan el trabajo por ti.

Comment: Referencia obligadísima: https://medium.com/@unrob/que-has-intentado-12b31d36bc89#.vjxkvwi0y

Comment: @astrojuanlu buena! No sabía que habían hecho una traducción

Comment: Perdon, se me paso poner mi codigo ya lo he agregado.

Comment: Pues los que han votado negativo pueden ya revisar su voto. Gracias @Gemasoft

Comment: Gracias, agregue mi respuesta ya que logre arreglar mi algoritmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontre una manera bastante elegante para conseguir lo que buscaba:

```
def getDigitalRoot(num):
    return num if num == 0 else num % 9 or 9
```

De esta forma resolvi el problema que tenia al poner 99 por ejemplo, antes me retornaba 0 y ahora me da 9 correctamente.

Comment: Esta respuesta *es* correcta, pero sería interesante saber *por qué*.  Sin una justificación matemática o al menos alguna referencia, la respuesta de César me parece bastante más adecuada.

Comment: Es la prueba del nueve (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prueba_del_nueve). De hecho, no entiendo porqué el nombre de "raiz digital" :P

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion

Comment: @Darkhogg, el problema de la respuesta de Cesar es que se usa recursion y no es necesario, por cuestiones de performance es mejor evitar la recursion.

Answer (score 6):

Usando una función recursiva, puedes hacer algo así:

```
def raiz_digital(numero):
    suma = sum(int(digito) for digito in str(numero))
    if suma < 10:
        return suma
    else:
        return raiz_digital(suma)

print raiz_digital(12345) # Resultado: 6
print raiz_digital(98765) # Resultado: 8
```

Lo que hace primero es calcular la suma de todos los dígitos convirtiendo el entero a una cadena:

```
>>> numero = 12345
>>> [digito for digito in str(numero)]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Luego cada dígito se convierte nuevamente a entero para ser sumado con la función `sum`:

```
>>> [int(digito) for digito in str(numero)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> sum([int(digito) for digito in str(numero)])
15
```

Se verifica que el resultado sea un número de un dígito (`suma < 10`) y se usa recursión en caso sea mayor de un dígito para obtener finalmente la raíz digital.

### Actualización

Utilizando la sugerencia de @Darkhogg, he cambiado la lista de comprensión por un generador, lo cual solo afecta la línea de la suma. Se cambió de:

```
suma = sum([int(digito) for digito in str(numero)])
```

A:

```
suma = sum(int(digito) for digito in str(numero))
```

Comment: Si todo lo que vas a hacer con la lista es calcular la suma, es mejor si utilizas un generador en su lugar: `sum(int(digito) for digito in str(numero))`

Comment: @Darkhogg cierto, la actualizo. Gracias por notarlo

Answer (score 2):

El problema puede resolverse sin recursión y utilizando el **builtin** reduce y el hecho de que en Python las cadenas de texto son iterables al igual que las listas.

```py
def digital_root(n):
    n = str(n)
    while(len(n) > 1):
        n = str(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(int, n)))
    return int(n)

print(digital_root(99))
print(digital_root(127))
```

Resultado

```
9
1
```

La raíz digital de 127 es 1 y no 10 (aparece en la pregunta):

- 1 + 2 + 7 -> 10 -> 1 + 0 -> 1

Answer (score 1):

La raíz digital de n es igual al residuo de dividir n para 9
dr(n)= n mod 9

esto se demuestra en

https://www.todoexpertos.com/preguntas/63pngi45njkno6f3/cual-es-el-procedimiento-que-permite-expresar-la-raiz-digital-por-medio-de-la-funcion-parte-entera-piso

El único inconveniente es que si n es múltiplo de 9, n mod 9 = 0 y queremos que salga 9.
Esto se resuelve con la función

dr(n) = (n - 1) mod 9 + 1

En Python esto quedaría
def getDigitalRoot(num):
    return (num-1)%9 +1

Comment: Esa respuesta la encontre para un problema de los iniciales de Codewars, y funciona.